# Looking for a sensor data platform

Tags: linux, open-source, data-visualization

We have plenty of sensor data (timestamp,value,errorflags and some metadata) and need a data platform to save, visualize and access sensor data.

The platform should have:

- User Interface for data visualization
- User management and roles for access management
- Open source license for local installations (linux please)
- API for data submission and data access
- PHP client library available
- Scalable and fast for timeseries handling
- Ideally written in PHP for easy extension with own modules

Ideally this platform is for sensor data something like [OwnCloud](https://owncloud.org) is for documents.

**EDIT** due to comment from @Mawg:

The primary objective of the platform is to store data. Data has to be stored first, before viewing. Viewing data should comprise basic time series charts and excel/csv download, but should be extensible by modules we could write by ourself. For each viewing process the data series and the timespan should be adjustable.

The purpose of roles is to have different access rights for data series.

Triggering alarms could be a nice feature but is not essential at a first step. We could build an extension for that by ourself. There are plenty ideas for that (including triggering [IFTTT](https://ifttt.com/) and the like).

We need to run the sensor platform internally even without link to the internet.

Comment: Do you just want to visualize the data as it arrives? Or do you want to store in a database first and then visualize from that? Can you give us more idea of what you mean by visualize? I.,e.what kind of reports do you want to generate? Histograms, pie charts, grid data? Per test run, hour, day, week, month? Export to CSV, etc? What do those roles do? Just admin & normal user, or something else that you can specify? Do you want to trigger alarms on certain readings (email, sms, etc)? As always, the more precise the question, the better its chances of getting an answer and I am interested in it.